# How to add new string/line below certain line in file which contains multiple same lines throughout a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, scripting

I'm writing a bash script. So, how can I add new string/line below certain line in file which contains multiple same lines of text throughout a file in BASH?
For example file could contain:

```
line 1
line 2a
line 3
line 4
line 2a
Line 5
line 6
line 2a
line 7
line 8
```

Is it possible to add another string only below `line 2a` which comes immediately after `line4` and ignore other `line 2a`s? I've tried this with `sed` but it adds string bellow every `line 2a`.

This is what I've tried (also I'm working with OSX):

```
sed -i.bak "/^$line/a \ 
    $entry" $file_path && rm "$file_path.bak"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you give a better definition of the conditions? "line 2a which comes immediately after line4" is not quite formal. Is it "find two consecutive lines with arbitrary text and replace"? Or do you want to always replace the second occurence of "line 2a"?

Comment: @brunorey - I've updated question.

Comment: So, I only want to add string after second appearance of  `line 2a`, and add it below the line `line 2a`.

Comment: Yes it is possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want with the provided sample data:

```
sed '/line 4/{N;/\nline 2a/ aAPPEND
}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sed` in your script:

```
> sed -E 's/^line 2a$/\0\n/' < file
line 1
line 2a

line 3
line 4
line 2a

Line 5
line 6
line 2a

line 7
line 8
```

Comment: This will add a new line after every `line 2a`. OP, however, only wanted a new line if it is preceeded by `line 4`.